# wp_list_categories set order manually?

Tags: categories

Is it possible to do this? In the codex the 'orderby' option does not allow manual ordering (only ascending ID, name, count, slug etc).

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    wp_list_categories('include=16,17,15&title_li=<h3>' . __('By Content') . '</h3>' ); 
?>
```

This is currently alphabetical since I havent included the 'orderby' statement. I want them ordered 17,15,16 but only these 3 cats which are not alphabetical.

Is this possible?

Comment: The [Category Order and Taxonomy Terms Order plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-terms-order/) may solve the issue:

Answer (score 0):

I would use [get_categories()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) to first get an associative array of all the categories and then sort it how you want it.

```
$categories = get_categories('include=16,17,15');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, replaced my code with your suggestion and it disappears completely.

Comment: Maybe read up on the docs (that I even linked). It doesn't print out the categories as a link but instead returns an array. You then have to sort it with a comparison function and then write a loop (maybe foreach) that will print the list. The [PHP docs](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/) will help you.

Comment: Thanks, read those already before posting, seems like it isnt possible without a bunch of complex coding which is beyond me.

Comment: Yes, I don't know about a way to do this with Wordpress alone. But it's not that hard to write a solution in PHP. And it's always good to know PHP when developing Wordpress Themes.